# Display http param if value is not empty

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Into React application I use this code to set value as url path param:

```
  const [exchangeId, setExchangeId] = useState('');

.....
    const endURL = `?page=${paginationState.activePage}&sort=${paginationState.sort},${paginationState.order}&exchangeId=${exchangeId}`;
.....
```

When I don't set with some value `exchangeId` I get always empty url param `exchangeId=`

Do you know how I can implement a check if `exchangeId` is not set to not include `exchangeId=` into http link?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use conditional (ternary) operators.

```js
const exchangeId = '';
const paginationState = {
  activePage: 1,
  sort: 1,
  order: 1
}
const endURL = `?page=${paginationState.activePage}&sort=${paginationState.sort}&order=${paginationState.order}${exchangeId ? `&exchangeId=${exchangeId}` : ''}`;
console.log(endURL);
```